# Woo custom badges/bubbles conditions

Tags: woocommerce

I create a custom badge/bubble "New!" based on time published:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', function() {
#add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', function() {

        $postdate      = get_the_time( 'Y-m-d' ); // Post date
        $postdatestamp = strtotime( $postdate );  // Timestamped post date
        $newness       = 10;                      // Newness in days
        if ( ( time() - ( 60 * 60 * 24 * $newness ) ) < $postdatestamp ) {

               echo '<div class="woo-entry-new-badge"><div class="woo-cust-new-badge">' . esc_html__( 'New!', 'woocommerce' ) . '</div></div>';

        }
}, 20 );
```

But i want to add conditional to show if "on sale" is not set.
How should look like?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WC_Product::is_on_sale()](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productis_on_sale/) – Returns whether or not the product is on sale.

```php
function my_callback_function() {
    global $product;

    $postdate = get_the_date( 'Y-m-d', $product->get_id() ); // Post date   
    $postdatestamp = strtotime( $postdate ); // Timestamped post date
    $newness = 10; // Newness in days

    $onsale = $product->is_on_sale();

    if ( ( time() - ( 60 * 60 * 24 * $newness ) ) < $postdatestamp && !$onsale ) {
        echo '<div class="woo-entry-new-badge"><div class="woo-cust-new-badge">' . esc_html__( 'New!', 'woocommerce' ) . '</div></div>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'my_callback_function', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: Thank for the fast answer! Working like a charm!